# Mysql query with select all and select sum

Tags: mysql, select, sum

Here I have student table, have fields: `id`,`name`,`score`.

Result will get 4 columns: `id`, `name`, `score`, and sum of score.

I need to combine two line, can I combine two command ?

```
select * from student
select sum(score) from student
```

Comment: Please provide a sample table and output.

Comment: Are you sure you need to combine it? I mean, first query will return a row for each student, while second query will return just one number, no rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *, (select sum(score) from student) as score_sum
from student
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar case. For me, the following worked:

```
SELECT *, sum(score) as score_sum FROM student
```

So no need for the extra SELECT but make sure that the * comes before the sum()

Comment: This will only return 1 row